# OpenSSL 1.0.0d Compilation then DLL generation

Tags: c++, c, openssl, compilation

**Situation**

Hi, I downloaded the OpenSSL 1.0.0d pack, and it contains the all the source code written in C. Iam interested in the Crypto library to check the implementation of symmetric/asymmetric cipher...etc.

**Question**

**1/** I am confused about the way to compile this package.
**2/** How can i generate a DLL File from this package ?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

which platform are you trying to compile this on? Compiling OpenSSL is very easy. Go thru the file INSTALL that is part of the source files and it will give you step by step instructions on what to do. 
If you are interested in compiling OpenSSL on a unix platform, you just need to use the provided Configure script, it will automatically detect the paltform and generate the appropriate make files.

Comment: thx for your quick answer, I need to compile it on windows. So which version of MS visual studio should I use ? i have MS visual studio c++ 6.0, it should be ok for this version?

Comment: check the INSTALL.W32 file, Visual studio 6 should be fine. As a side not you may want to move to a higher version of Visual Studio as 6 is dated. You can just download the basic version of the latest Visual Studio from MSDN for free.

Comment: Re, look i found "Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.0d Light" in this link http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html. Does it replace what should I do manually ?